# Shell script git update error logging

Tags: git, shell

I want to log the errors from my shell script running git_update in multiple repositories. Right now I am able to log all errors that occur with running `$(git_update 2>&1 >/dev/null)`. This saves the error output as it should, and prints it out at the end of the script. But while running the script I want all the output of the git_update aswell as printing only errors at the end. This is so that all the errors don't get "lost" in the output feed.

Is there any way for me to run the git_update for my repositories in a regular way, while also saving only the error output to a variable so that I can echo it after the script is done?